# Non-cubic blocks in Adaptive Mesh Refinement

Tags: finite-difference, adaptive-mesh-refinement

Most Adaptive Mesh Refinement softwares/logic have cubic blocks. I have explored the BoxLib library and it ONLY supports cubic blocks. To be more precise it supports non-cubic blocks at the coarsest grid level but fails to maintain this non-cubic size when the boxes are refined. ***I wanted to know if there are block structured AMR packages/softwares which support non-cubic blocks*** ?

Comment: Do you mean "cubic" as opposed to tetrahedral, or do you want to imply that each cell really is a cube with parallel and equally sized edges?

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth: Hi, what I meant was that in block-structured AMR we usually have blocks which have dimensions like : 4x4x4 cells or 8x8x8 cells or basically 'm x m x m' cells. I have never come across block sizes which are like : 8x4x2 or 16x8x4 i.e. the number of cells in each direction is different.

Comment: What you describe is called anisotropic refinement. It's not hugely popular, but there are software libraries that do have that. My own one, deal.II, does for example: https://www.dealii.org/8.4.1/doxygen/deal.II/step_30.html